# Linear Transformation Matricies

Tags: linear-algebra

Prove that the map $T: P_m(F) \to P_m(F)$ given by $T(q(x)) = \frac{d}{dx}((3x - 2)q(x))$ is injective and thus invertible. For $m = 2$, find $\mathcal{M}(T)$ and compute its inverse. Can you find $T^{-1}$ for general $m$?

I think I have a fairly good understanding of the first part,as multiplying a nonzero polynomial $q$ by $3x-2$ increases its degree by 1, and then differentiating once reduces the degree by 1. So $T$ is an operator on $P_m(F)$. Every polynomial whose first derivative equals 0 is in the form $a$, or just a constant. Since nothing can be just a constant as it is multiplied by $3x - 2$, the null space of $T$, $\text{null}(T) = \{0\}$. Hence, $T$ is injective, and therefore, it is invertible.

However, I'm stuck on the second and third questions. I know that since polynomials of degree two look like $ax^2 + bx + c$, the linear transformation take them to $9ax^2+2(3b+2a)c+(3c+2b)$, but I don't know how to put this in a matrix.

Comment: The matrix of a linear transformation only makes sense with respect to some basis. So, choose a basis for $P_m(F)$.

Comment: So, say the standard basis $(x^m, x^{m-1}, \ldots, x, 1)$?

Answer (score 0):

Let us look at the standard base of $P_2(F): \{1,x,x^2\},$ and see how $T$ "acts" on it:

$$T(1)=3=3\cdot1+0\cdot x+0\cdot x^2$$
$$T(x)=6x-2=-2\cdot1 +6\cdot x +0\cdot x^2$$
$$T(x^2)=9x^2-4x=0\cdot 1 + (-4)\cdot x + 9\cdot x^2$$

These are the coordinates with respect to the standard base, placing them in columns of a matrix will give us the result:$$\begin{bmatrix}3 & -2 &0 \\0 & 6 & -4 \\0 & 0 & 9 \end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: Okay. Thanks so much! What about finding the general inverse for the general matrix? The general pattern seems evident, but I'm a little stumped on the inverse of the general matrix.

Comment: @user460702 I would find the inverse of the matrix in the answer, and determine the pattern.